# Ruby driver tests failing for credit card with luhn algorithm

Tags: ruby, algorithm, class

I worked up a working code to check if a credit card is valid using luhn algorithm:

```
class CreditCard
  def initialize(num)
    @@num_arr = num.to_s.split("")
    raise ArgumentError.new("Please enter exactly 16 digits for the credit card number.") 

    if @@num_arr.length != 16
      @num = num
    end


  def check_card
    final_ans = 0
    i = 0
    while i < @@num_arr.length
      (i % 2 == 0) ? ans = (@@num_arr[i].to_i * 2) : ans = @@num_arr[i].to_i
      if ans > 9
        tens = ans / 10
        ones = ans % 10
        ans = tens + ones
      end
      final_ans += ans
      i += 1
    end
    final_ans % 10 == 0 ? true : false
  end

end
```

However, when I create driver test codes to check for it, it doesn't work:

```
card_1 = CreditCard.new(4563960122001999)
card_2 = CreditCard.new(4563960122001991)
p card_1.check_card
p card_2.check_card
```

I've been playing around with the code, and I noticed that the driver code works if I do this:

```
card_1 = CreditCard.new(4563960122001999)
p card_1.check_card
card_2 = CreditCard.new(4563960122001991)
p card_2.check_card
```

I tried to research before posting on why this is happening. Logically, I don't see why the first driver codes wouldn't work. Can someone please assist me as to why this is happening?

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

You are using a class variable that starts with `@@`, which is shared among all instances of `CreditCard` as well as the class (and other related classes). Therefore, the value will be overwritten every time you create a new instance or apply `check_card` to some instance. In your first example, the class variable will hold the result for the last application of the method, and hence will reflect the result for the last instance (`card_2`).

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation! It makes sense. I will change the class variables to instance variables to solve the issue.